# Can I make jQuery's load(); appear slowly?

Tags: jquery

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#post_submit").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    $("#show").load("post.php", {
      submit: $("#post_submit").val(),
      title: $("#title").val(),
      body: $("#body").val(),
      tags: $("#tags").val()
    });
  });
});
```

This works fine, and the information is displayed in  without the page reloading (yay), but it's not very smooth. I was wondering how I could make it appear slowly, like `$(div).show("slow");` or `$(div).toggle("slow")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this would be to load the new content into a hidden container. Then, chain a show('slow') to the end of the load event.

As shown in the [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/load#fn), load returns the jQuery object, so it can be chained with other events.

Something along the lines of

```
$("#show").hide();
$("#show").load("post.php", {
  submit: $("#post_submit").val(),
  title: $("#title").val(),
  body: $("#body").val(),
  tags: $("#tags").val()
}).show("slow");
```

Comment: Using this code, `show()` will run before `post.php` has finished loading - I doubt this will be noticeable in most situations - but it might be worth adding `show()` to the callback, which will only run once `post.php` has loaded.